# NativeScript flat ActionBar overlapping ScrollView

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, ios11.4

I have a flat ActionBar `flat: true` in CSS and a `ScrollView` inside of a `GridLayout`. The view initially renders with the `ScrollView` underneath the ActionBar. A `margin-top` on the `GridLayout` (top level view) worked fine with the default, translucent ActionBar.

This is in NativeScript 4.2.4 and NativeScript Angular 6.1.10.

[image: action bar scrollview]

*EDIT:* The issue appears to be related with some delayed rendering. This seems to happen when the previous screen has the ActionBar hidden.

Comment: What version of NativeScript are you using? In NS 5 I am seeing the opposite; when flat="true" the ActionBar adds an extra gap before the page content loads. Also you may want to phrase this as a question; right now it reads like a bug report.

Comment: NS 4.2.4. I know the safe area was added for NS 5 but I am not sure of the upgrade path for NS Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a suggestion that says to remove the transition effect between pages that do and don't have the ActionBar visible.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1377